# Does "He might be getting ruder" make sense?

Tags: sentence-meaning

When my son acts up to me, I see it in two ways.

> First, "did I do something wrong with him?" and the other is that he might be getting ruder.

I'm not sure "he might be getting ruder" makes sense.

Do that have the same meaning with: "he might become ruder"?

English is not my first language. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are using **getting** correctly there to mean "becoming".

> Your son can be getting more mature.
>
> Your son can be getting more rebellious.
>
> Your son can be getting taller.

With regard to your question about *Did I do something wrong with him*...

That question is OK too. It would be understood to mean *Have I made some error when raising him?*  That is, in the way you have raised him.